# Keep specific notification on the top of the notifications center

Tags: iphone, widget, uilocalnotification, notificationcenter

I want to simulate a lightweight iPhone "widget" by having a specific notification in the notifications center that opens the app and performs a quick action (i.e. "Add new task").

The problem is that when I get new notifications (push or local notifications), the widget task is pushed down, and the most recent notification becomes the first one.

I tried solving this by adding a repeat interval for the "widget" notification, but the problem is that it duplicates this notification, and since I'm in the background I can't cancel the previous ones.

Any ideas?